# How to convert an interface with MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I made some research in the mapStruct documentation but did not find or understood what I could do to achieve this: the conversation of an entity containing an interface to a flat DTO object.

Here the entity with the attribute:

```
public class Group {
    ...

    private IUser user;

    ...
}
```

Here the DTO:

```
public GroupDTO {

    private Long idUser;

    private String username;
}
```

We try this mapping :

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "user.id", target = "idUser"),
        @Mapping(source = "user.name", target = "username")})
GroupDTO toDTO(Group entity);
```

With a classic mapping, mapStruct generates an error (IUser is abstract; cannot be instantiated).

Any idea ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Should we use the @aftermapping to make a manual mapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure its the best way to do it...

But we used @AfterMapping to create manually in default method the object to implement on interface.

We had to delete @InheritInverseConfiguration for reverse operation.

Answer (score 1):

hi i am using map struct version : 1.3.1.Final and i mapped from interface to dto easily:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OrderSummeryMapper {
    AllocatedOrderSummeryResponse toOrderSummery (AllocatedOrderSummery orderSummery);
}
```

my dto:

```
@Data //lombok annotation
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AllocatedOrderSummeryResponse implements Serializable {
     Integer customerId;
     String deliveryCategory;
}
```

interface:

```
public interface AllocatedOrderSummery {

    Integer getCustomerId();
    String getDeliveryCategory();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with an [object factory method](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories):

```
public IUser createIUser() {
    return new User();
}
```

This factory method will the be invoked if an instance of `IUser` is needed.